# Can't commit with Github Windows, no reason given

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have been forced to use other apps, and the command line since Github for Windows is not allowing me to commit changes. I would like to understand what's the problem, but I simply get a prompt with this message:

```
Commit failed
Failed to create new commit
```

Then, it gives me the option of go to the Git Shell or to cancel. While I am not an expert with the terminal, I am able to make commits when I choose to go to the Git Shell (or to any other application for that matter).

I am using Github 2.0.5 on Windows 7.

Comment: Hi there, I'm one of the GitHub for Windows devs. Can you drop us a line at support@github.com with the log from https://help.github.com/articles/accessing-the-github-for-windows-log so we can investigate?

Comment: I will send you the log with the subject line: Stack Overflow - Commit on Windows

Answer (score 0):

After an exchange with the Github for Windows developers, the issue has something to do with Windows inability to work with paths when they're too long. The node_modules folders generated by Node.js [is the culprit of this issue in my particular case](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6960).

However, the node_modules folders in my repository are gitignored. The fact that even when gitignored they create a problem in Github for Windows means the developers have to address the situation.

I expect a response or a patch from the developers soon. They have been very helpful. In the meantime, I am using SourceTree as my Windows Git GUI.

Comment: I have the same issue that you did. It's now two years later. Was your problem resolved?

Comment: I no longer use the Windows app, as I'm on the Mac. I suggest you contact the developer, he posted a comment above.